# List IndexError out of range in GAE

Tags: python, list, google-app-engine, google-maps, exception

This geocoding code works locally, but not in the server, it gets the address in the form of `self.request.get('address')` and returns the `ndb.GeoPt()` value from a `get_lat_long(address)` function.

So, how come I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~map-jobs/2.371278632227250958/main.py", line 453, in post
    profile.geopoint = get_lat_long(self.request.get('address'))
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~map-jobs/2.371278632227250958/main.py", line 17, in get_lat_long
    lat = data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

With this code:

```
def get_lat_long(address):
  address = cgi.escape(address.replace(" ","+"))
  sensor = "true"
  url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&sensor="+ sensor
  result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
  data = json.loads(result.content)
  lat = data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
  long = data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
  return ndb.GeoPt(str(lat) +","+ str(long))
```

What is the correct way of writing this in the google-app-engine server?

Comment: Try printing `data['results']` to see if it actually exists

Comment: The error is pretty clear: `data['result']` is empty.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti Yea you just edited it, you didn't say what was the error before, i was stating the same thing.

Comment: I just used `data`, and it says `{u'status': u'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT', u'error_message': u'You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.', u'results': []}`. That's why I got a different results. **Maps API should become on**, can't get generate it without API. Thanks, I can take it from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `len()` to check index existence.

Answer (score 1):

`data['results'][0]` is actually empty.

This happens when there *are* not results. Usually, I just put it in a `try/catch` block, and except an `IndexError`:

```
try:
    data['results'][0]....
except IndexError, e:
    print "No data found"  # You can use a logger here too
```

In your case, put a `try/catch` block around the following code, and find a way to deal with the error:

```
  lat = data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
  long = data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
```

This happened to me a lot, when I was working with google drive, since a lot of the doucments did not have `text/html` as an output format, I was always getting `KeyError`. In your case you are dealing with google maps, and if there *are* results there *should* be `geometry` and the other keys in the dict, however, you may also choose to add `KeyError` to your except clause to be extra precautious.